# Webservice with Oracle Weblogic 10.rG3 error with boolean and integer

Tags: java, web-services, oracle, weblogic

I'm doing a few tests in weblogic to create webservices. Everything was ok, until I tried to add an Integer and a Boolean variable.

When trying to test my webservice via weblogic server, the following error appears:

```
[Server CodecHandler] Failed to encode fault -> beans.controls.imoveis.impl.ImovelImpl.setVagagaragem(java.lang.Boolean)
```

I had "solved" the Integer problem, by changing variables and database types to String. Since that isn't what I want, I tried solving this issue, though, with no success. In my service's xsd, the types are set as `xs:boolean` and `xs:int`. In Postgres database, it's the same, `Boolean` and `Integer` for columns types. I tried a few changes, but no matter what I do, I keep getting this error.

Does anybody knows what is happening here?